# Как сделать очередь из методов в android без паттерна command

Tags: java, android, mvp, moxy, androidx

**Краткий вопрос: Как поставить вызов методов в очередь без паттерна "Команда"?**

**ИЛИ**

**Есть ли альтернатива Moxy, поддерживающая Android Jetpack (androidx)?**

Делаю приложение на архитектуре MVP. Впервые без библиотеки [Moxy](https://github.com/Arello-Mobile/Moxy), т.к. она не поддерживает использование элементов из Android Jetpack (androidx.*).

Вкратце, схема такова. Есть презентер, в котором хранится некий `Proxy`. Оба они поставляются во `View` через Dagger. Дальше `View` передает свой экземпляр в `Proxy`, дабы тот мог манипулировать этой вьюшкой.

Т.о. : Presenter -> Proxy -> View (`->` - вызов методов)

Мне сейчас необходимо создать `Proxy` между `Presenter` и `View` который кэшировал все вызовы методов у `View`. То есть понятно, что `Proxy` должен реализовывать интерфейс `View` и на вызовах методов как-то их складывать в очередь, если, например, на данный момент ни одна View не привязана к `Proxy`. Непонятен лишь механизм складывания вызовов в очередь. Сейчас это реализовано через паттерн "Команда", однако это не очень удобно по нескольким причинам, которые я опишу ниже.

**Как все реализовано сейчас**

Класс `VPStorage` хранит ссылки на все презентеры и привязанные к ним вью. Тут все просто.

```
public class VPStorage{


private static HashMap<IPresenter, ArrayList<IView>> viewPresenterMap;

public VPStorage(){
    viewPresenterMap = new HashMap<>();
}

/**
 * This method should be invoked from views
 * @param presenter - presenter, which associated with current view
 * @param view - view (fragment, activity, etc.)
 */
public static void addPresenterToView(IPresenter presenter, IView view){
    ArrayList<IView> viewsList;
    if(!viewPresenterMap.containsKey(presenter) || viewPresenterMap.get(presenter) == null){
        viewsList = new ArrayList<>();
        viewsList.add(view);
        viewPresenterMap.put(presenter, viewsList);
    }else{
        viewsList = viewPresenterMap.get(presenter);
        if(!viewsList.contains(view)){
            viewsList.add(view);
        }else{
            Log.v(TAG, "presenter " + presenter + " already attached to view " + view);
        }
    }
    CommandExecutor.executeAllCommands(presenter);
}

public static void removeViewFromPresenter(IPresenter presenter, IView view){
    if(viewPresenterMap.get(presenter) != null){
        viewPresenterMap.get(presenter).remove(view);
    }
}

public static boolean hasPresenter(IPresenter presenter){
    return viewPresenterMap.containsKey(presenter);
}

public static ArrayList<IView> getPresenterViews(IPresenter presenter){
    return viewPresenterMap.get(presenter);
}


}
```

Класс `CommandExecutor` ответственен за хранение вызовов методов у соответствующих `View` и за правильное исполнение "Стратегий" см. `executeAllCommands()`

```
public class CommandExecutor{

private static HashMap<IPresenter, Queue<Command>> commandsQueue;


public CommandExecutor(){
    commandsQueue = new HashMap<>();
}

public static void sendCommand(Command command){
    commandsQueue.get(command.getPresenter()).add(command);
}

public static void executeAllCommands(IPresenter presenter){
    try{
        for(Command currentCommand : commandsQueue.get(presenter)){
            Strategy commandStrategy = currentCommand.getStrategy();
            if(commandStrategy == Strategy.EVERY_CREATION){
                executeCommand(currentCommand);
            }else if(commandStrategy == Strategy.SINGLE){
                executeCommand(currentCommand);
                removeCommand(presenter, currentCommand);
            }
        }
    }catch(NoSuchElementException | NullPointerException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        Log.v(TAG, "command queue to view is empty");
    }
}

public static void removeCommand(IPresenter presenter, Command command){
    if(commandsQueue.get(presenter) != null){
        commandsQueue.get(presenter).remove(command);
    }
}

public static void sendCommand(IPresenter presenter, Command command){
    if(commandsQueue.get(presenter) != null){
        commandsQueue.get(presenter).add(command);
    }
}


private static void executeCommand(Command command){
    ArrayList<IView> linkedViews = VPStorage.getPresenterViews(command.getPresenter());
    try{
        for(IView view : linkedViews){
            command.setView(view);
            command.use();
        }
    }catch(NullPointerException ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(TAG, "There is no linked views to presenter " + command.getPresenter().getClass());
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
        Log.d(TAG, "Current IView not inherited by necessary class");
    }
}
}
```

Ну и класс `Command`, который отправляется из презентера в `CommandExecutor` и содержит в себе стратегию для исполнения метода, переопределенный метод `use()` в котором мы говорим что и как делать с `View`, сам презентер и интерфейс `View`.

```
public abstract class Command<T extends IView>{

@Nullable
private T view;
private IPresenter presenter;
private Strategy strategy;

public abstract void use();

public IPresenter getPresenter(){
    return presenter;
}

public Command<T> setPresenter(IPresenter presenter){
    this.presenter = presenter;
    return this;
}

@Nullable
public T getView(){
    return view;
}

public Command<T> setView(@Nullable T view){
    this.view = view;
    return this;
}

public Strategy getStrategy(){
    return strategy;
}

public Command<T> setStrategy(Strategy strategy){
    this.strategy = strategy;
    return this;
}
}
```

И здесь сразу становится очевидно: чтобы вызвать даже один простой метод у `View`, нам необходимо создавать собственную реализацию класса `Command`, переопределять метод `use()`, подставлять презентер и стратегию в класс `Command`. С точки зрения рациональности здесь все ужасно. Единственное, что можно упростить- поставить дефолтное значение стратегии, однако и это тоже не поможет.

Как, например, простой запуск `progressbar` происходит сейчас:

```
CommandExecutor.sendCommand(new Command<ILoginFragment>(){
        @Override
        public void use(){
            getView().startLoading();
        }
    }.setPresenter(this)
    .setStrategy(Strategy.EVERY_CREATION));
```

Именно по причине описанной выше, я хочу перейти от глобальной структуре, где все эти классы у нас синглтоны, к более локальной, где задействован только `Presenter`, `View` и `Proxy`. Поэтому, если вы знаете, или предполагаете как разрешить проблему выше, или у вас на примете есть библиотеки по типу `Moxy`, работающие с `androidx` , то прошу в ответы.

Comment: первая ошибка что Proxy это структурный паттерн, те по сути вы также должны обращаться с презентера ко View. а уже в нем реализуйте CommandQueue и  не обязательно реализовывать command аналогично moxy, можно инкапсулриовать sendCommand и внутри, там же может быть и router или StateMachine. Те в итоге вместо sendCommand будет так что в презентре вы будете делать view.showProgress() если необходимо задать стратегию то будет view.showProgress().withStrategy(Strategy.SINGLE). Так должен чистый proxy выглядеть. Оч сложно дать ответ на вопрос одназначно, тут целая реализация мини либы

Comment: С помощью DI и локальных синглтонов можно подобное сделать ну тогда вопрос когда их зачищать, также как и у вас когда VPStorage. Можно попробовать с помощью ANdroidViewModel мы делали такое, оч неплохо получается. Те ответов тут может быть множество, явно что вопрос слишком общий. Кратко можно ответить так, что вы можете для каждого презентера уже готовить в DI Command<View> с default стратегий а если надо изменить то так как выше писал расширить класс парочкой абстрактных методов